# Issue with Polybase-from synapse analytics DW on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-synapse, external-tables, polybase

I am trying to create an external data source from azure synapse DW to S3 compatible bucket/storage. But I am getting an error about the unsupported URI. As per the Microsoft documents, S3 is compatible from synapse analytics. After creating the scoped credential which was successful. I am trying to execute below command.

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE s3_DSWITH( LOCATION = 's3://cloudstorage.com:443/', CREDENTIAL = S3_ECS);

Msg 105007, Level 16, State 1, Line 6Scheme of the input URI is not supported. Please revise the following scheme and try again: 's3'

Comment: Azure Synapse Analytics does not natively support the 's3' URI scheme for connecting to S3-compatible storage.
To connect Azure Synapse Analytics to an S3-compatible storage service, you can consider using Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're referring to this link, am I correct?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-s3-compatible
It says it is available in SQL Server 2022 on-premises, it is not available in Azure Synapse Analytics.